# Caesar Cypher Program: String index out of range error

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

Is it because of two if and else statements inside of each other?

I am working on a Caesar Cipher program for class. I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Chandler\Desktop\CSCI220-S16-Assign2-CaesarEncode-CTL.py", line 31, in main
    print("You coded message is: ", (code(message)))
  File "C:\Users\Chandler\Desktop\CSCI220-S16-Assign2-CaesarEncode-CTL.py", line 25, in code
    textInput += alphabet[letterPos]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Just a side note I will also be creating another loop section of this program to unwrap the text back to the initial input

```
def main():

    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    message = input("Enter the message you wish to be encoded: ")
    message = message.lower()

    key = eval(input("Enter the key shift: "))

    def code(message):
        textInput = ""
        for ch in message:
            if ch in alphabet:          
                letterPos = alphabet.find(ch) + key
                if letterPos > 26:
                    letterPos % key
                else:

                    letterPos + key
                textInput += alphabet[letterPos]

            else:
                cyphertext += ch
        return textInput

    print("You coded message is: ", (code(message)))



#end main
main()
```

Comment: The if block is wrong. You are not assigning the results and the operation is not correct.

Comment: You want to use `(letter + key) % 26` to perform a shift and map it onto the alphabet.

Comment: This is definitely a school exercise. I am not sure if we should provide direct answers.

Comment: why are you using `eval` you could use the `input` like that

Answer (score 0):

Insert print statements to see the value of letterPos as the program goes along. Find out when it's 26 or larger. 26 or larger would require an if statement: if letterPos >= 26.

Comment: Debuggers cost nothing nowadays!

Comment: Actually I still have one on layaway

Answer (score 0):

You already shift the letter with `letterPos = alphabet.find(ch) + key` and you wrap it around when necessary in the `if letterPos > 26` block. However, you must use modulo 26, not the `key` value. Additionally, the else block is both superfluous and also offending, since you shift the letter a second time with no wrap around.

You should use the modulo every time since a branch is slower. All in all, this should fix the problem.

```
if ch in alphabet:
    letterPos = (alphabet.find(ch) + key) % 26
    textInput += alphabet[letterPos]
else:
    textInput += ch
```

Also, mind the name `cyphertext`, which isn't defined anywhere.